# Cannot access /home/user directory with permissions drwxrwxrwx

Tags: permissions

My company's server uses Linux Redhat Enterprise version. I notice other users' home directories have permission drwxrwxrwx. However, I cannot cd or ls other users' home directories. Why this happens?

More backgrounds: My company has N machines 1, 2, 3, .. , N. Suppose there are userA, userB, userC, userD 4 users. Each user can log on any machine to access his own /home/user[A|B|C|D] directory.(From this behavior, I guess the data in the home directories is stored on a shared drive and then mounted on each machine). In addition, each user can see other users' /home/userA, /home/userB, etc with permission drwxrwxrwx. However, each user cannot cd or ls other users' home directories. What is my company's system setup to achieve this?

Comment: Are the home directories stored on a network share?

Comment: Looks your user lacks this permission.

Comment: @Jesse_b I guess the home directories are stored on a network share because my company has many machines and I can access my home folder from any machine for example.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 What do you mean by "your user lacks this permission"? Other user's home directory has drwxrwxrwx permissions so I should be able to access it in theory

Comment: Can you `ping` this device that seek?

Comment: May are being filtered in those home directories, from `ufw` firewall, `iptables` ban...

Comment: If this is on a netapp server, this is most likely from missconfigured ACLs.

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 What do you mean by "ping this device that seek"? I don't have root administrator access. Do you mean that if the home directory is mounted on the machine, then there are other factors to determine permission in addition to the drwxrwxrwx setting?

Comment: Is it the same network or different networks? Aren't those directories hidden, like '.home/user/'?

Comment: @Vasconcelos1914 It is the same network. More backgrounds: My company has N machines 1, 2, 3, .. , N. Suppose there are userA, userB, userC, userD 4 users. Each user can log on any machine to access his own /home/user[A|B|C|D] directory. In addition, each user can see other users' directories under /home/ with permission drwxrwxrwx. However, each user cannot cd or ls other users' home directories. What is my company's system setup to achieve this?

Comment: Type us output of '$ ip addr show' or '$ ifconfig' please.

Comment: In all likelihood, the storage server that's hosting the export with the home directories has ACLs set on the home directories that prohibit anyone but the owner from accessing them. The ACLs are going to override the Unix permissions so the `777` permissions don't matter. Logically, that's what's going on. I can't imagine that your company's IT department or administration would want people to access each other's home directories for the same reason that they wouldn't want everyone to access every network share throughout the company.